# How do you define an arbitrary sort sequence for views?

Tags: views

Take a look at the [Drupal issues queue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/views?page=3&order=priority&sort=desc&text=&status=Open&priorities=All&categories=All&version=All&component=All) and the Priority column.  If sorted in descending order you get critical, major, normal, and minor issues, in that order.  Since "normal" would not go between "major" and "minor" in alphabetical order, they've obviously defined a custom sequence to use for sorting.  How is this done in Drupal?

Is it merely sorting based on a numeric value that is not displayed?  Or is it more clever than that?

Comment: I don't know how it is for that specific case, but usually, Drupal sorts by a weight column which is an int. Higher values gets lower down in the list, and lower values gets higher up.

Comment: Two overlapping SO questions are: [question 2471361](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2471361), [question 13391284](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13391284). They demonstrate another technique: sorting view results in PHP.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Views has [`hook_views_query_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/docs%21docs.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/6), which lets you mess with the query object that it maintains.  It gets called before the query object gets converted to SQL.  You can change the sorting that is set in the UI with something like:

```
function mymodule_views_query_alter (&$view, &$query)
{
  $query->orderby = array('node.nid ASC');
}
```

Basically, the value you use is what would be after the `ORDER BY` in a normal query.  You should be able to use an [`ORDER BY CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case),

```
function mymodule_views_query_alter (&$view, &$query)
{
  $orderby = "
    CASE
      WHEN node.type = 'page' THEN 1
      WHEN node.type = 'article' THEN 2
    END ASC
  ";
  $query->orderby = array($orderby);
}
```

You will need to enable previewing the SQL in Views (it's in the main views settings, not with the settings for a particular view) to see the names to use.

Comment: For another code example (with `JOIN`), see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2494289/1270008).

Answer (score 5):

The key piece is found in the url:

```
http://drupal.org/project/issues/views?page=3&order=priority&sort=desc&text=&status=Open&priorities=All&categories=All&version=All&component=All
```

where it says `order=priority&sort=desc` which tells Views to order by priority in descending order.  If you click on the Priority header to resort the table based on that column, it shows this link:

```
http://drupal.org/project/issues/views?order=priority&sort=asc&page=4&text=&status=Open&priorities=All&categories=All&version=All&component=All
```

where once again the important bit is `order=priority&sort=asc`.

But no magic, this just means that there is a numeric field in the issue queue called priority that can and is sorted upon.

A confusion certainly is coming from the dropdown for Priorities mentioned by @Anil Sagar but that is different from the priority and is rather used within `priorities=All` or `priorities=#` whose numeric fields don't seem to align with those of priority.

Comment: If there is a numeric field named "priority" then why does it not match with the numbers in the "priority" field you see when you create an issue?  And why is the column labeled "Priority" highlighted when it has values that don't sort according to either numeric or alphabetical ordering?  There has to be some magic somewhere, which your answer doesn't explain.

Comment: @iconoclast Do you mean the numbers in the value attributes of the HTML input tags, like the ones shown in Anil Sagar's answer below? If so, I'd bet that those are the ID values of the Priority items, and Priorities have a numerical 'Priority' field as well as a name and ID. I'd guess that 'priorities' is a taxonomy vocabulary, and each individual 'Priority' has an ID, a name, a numerical 'Priority' value, probably a long text 'Description' field, and maybe other fields that do other stuff in the background. They'd be loaded by a relationship, via a Term Reference field.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's based on numeric sort. You can see the values in inspect element as shown below.

```
<select name="priorities" class="form-select" id="edit-priorities">
    <option value="All" selected="selected">- Any -</option>
    <option value="1">critical</option>
    <option value="4">major</option>
    <option value="2">normal</option>
    <option value="3">minor</option>
</select>
```

If it is based on numeric sort then it should show critical on top and major on last which is not ! So, i guess it is more clever than that !

Comment: Interesting: the integers have no logic to them at all.  If you remove "major" then the integers are assigned in alphabetical order (which makes no sense to do).  If "major" was added later, then I'd bet they were just careless with the order when the first built it, and only later realized that priorities NEED to be ordered based on importance, and not the alphabet.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, I couldn't get to use the answer given from @mpdonadio. This is the solution that worked for me after debugging it through `dpm()`.

```
function custom_shop_view_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if ($view->name == 'products' || $view->name == 'uc_catalog' ) {
    // Traverse through the 'orderby' part of the query.
    foreach ($query->orderby as &$orderby) {
      if ($orderby['field'] == 'uc_products_model') {
        $orderby = array(
          'field' => 'field_data_field_product_tag_node_entity_type',
          'direction' => 'ASC',
        );
      }
    }

    $query->add_orderby('node', 'changed', 'DESC');  
  } 
}
```

If addressed the orderby array by 'field' and 'direction', no SQL syntax errors were thrown.